# R: How can I repeat a line of code for all my rows?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I have a line of code,
tweet1 <- userTimeline("@VALUE", n=100)
I want this to continue based on the rows in my column.
So say I have a dataframe with one column, "Companies" and rows, Optus, Telstra, Samsung.,
I want to have a function that will automatically do:

tweet1 <- userTimeline("@Optus", n=100)

tweet2 <- userTimeline("@Telstra", n=100)

tweet3 <- userTimeline("@Samsung", n=100)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` loop or `lapply`. If your dataframe is called `df` you can do :

```
tweet_list <- lapply(paste0('@', df$Companies), userTimeline, n = 100)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! How about in this case, tweet_df <- as_tibble(map_df(tweet_list,as.data.frame))?

Comment: If you want to combine them into one dataframe use `tweet_df <- purrr::map_df(paste0('@', df$Companies), userTimeline, n = 100)`

Comment: Thanks Ronak, when I do that it's coming up with "argument 1  must be a data frame or a named atomic vector" do you know why this could be or what I could do?

Comment: When you do `tweet1 <- userTimeline("@Optus", n=100)` What does `class(tweet1)` return?

Comment: it returns list

Comment: and what does `class(tweet1[[1]])` return?

Comment: [1] "status"
attr(,"package")
[1] "twitteR"